# React Native: Error: Package name not found

Tags: android, react-native

After integrating RN into an existing Android project, I get the following error:

`Error: Package name not found in /home/.../AndroidManifest.xml    at Object.projectConfig (/home/.../rn_integrated_app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/config/index.js:74:11)    at Object.get project [as project]`

As I understand the problem is that there is no `package` attribute in the relevant AndroidManifest.xml file. Since my project has many flavors, the `package` attribute is added dynamically, while compiling, through app/build.gradle:

```
def pkgDataEntry = getRightValue(packagesData, variantMap)
variant.getMergedFlavor().applicationId = pkgDataEntry.pkg
```

So that the final merged manifest file **does** have the `package` attribute.

The error occurs here(`@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/config/index.js`):

```
  const packageName = userConfig.packageName || getPackageName(manifest);

  if (!packageName) {
    throw new Error(`Package name not found in ${manifestPath}`);
  }
```

Is there a way to make RN read the merged manifest file?
If not, how can I modify `userConfig` to contain the package name? I couldn`t find anything about it in the docs.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anybody encounters the same issue, when having multiple flavors and *AndroidManifest.xml* files,here`s my conclusion:
RN has some kind of a bug that it requires the **first** folder alphabetically, in *android/app/src*, which has *AndroidManifest.xml* file,to have the *package* attribute. Otherwise, it will throw an error.

A simple solution would be to create a dummy folder, e.g *aaa* (first alphabetically) and to create *AndroidManifest.xml* inside of it, with the following attribute - *package*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="aaa"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
        tools:node="remove"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 27):

For me, the solution was to add the "package" tag to the manifest tag.
I didn't have to create another dummy folder.

The manifest open tag now looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourProjectName">
```

Comment: Started having this issue in React Native project after upgrading Android Gradle Plugin to 7.2.0. Adding package attribute fixed this. Thanks!

Comment: @Aleksi But I dont understand - the package attribute is deprecated in new versions of react-native, it asked me to add it to build.gradle (namespace), but still got the error

Comment: [agree, why it does not compile without it?](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.69.3&to=0.72.4#RnDiffApp-android-app-src-main-AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: In the end, I managed to build it with the package specification, and then safely removed it afterwars (since libs were complaining it is deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error start after upgrade the sdkVersion from 31 to 33 and gradle version.

I did check the changes in git, and notice that the package attribute was removed from AndroidManifest.xml.

So I did add this attribute again.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.yourpackage">
```