# I encountered error trying to run a Android Build using React-native (error Failed to build the app: No package name found)

Tags: android, reactjs, node.js, react-native

I am new to Android. I cloned a github project(https://github.com/Expensify/App). I have been trying to run the android build, but it keeps failing. Here is the error message:

```
> new.expensify@1.4.14-0 android
> scripts/set-pusher-suffix.sh && npx react-native run-android --mode=developmentDebug --appId=com.expensify.chat.dev

warn Package react-native-flipper contains invalid configuration: "dependency.platforms.ios.project" is not allowed. Please verify it's properly linked using "react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers about this.
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, /home/danajayi/App/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, /home/danajayi/App/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/danajayi/App/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 389

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> error Failed to build the app: No package name found. We couldn't parse the namespace from neither your build.gradle[.kts] file at /home/danajayi/App/node_modules/react-native-blob-util/android/build.gradle nor your package in the AndroidManifest at null.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
error Failed to install the app.
```

Comment: Closing as this issue is related to the CLI: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli
Also you can find relevant information on the cofniguration support here:
https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/configuration.md

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the package name for your app could not be found by the Android build system.

This may occur for several reasons :

```
1 ) Neither the build.gradle nor the AndroidManifest.xml file contain the package name.
2 ) The build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml files both contain the package name, but the values are different.
3 ) An Android package name cannot contain the package name.
```

Closing as this issue is related to the CLI: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli
Also you can find relevant information on the cofniguration support here:
https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/configuration.md

Comment: Pratik, thanks for the response. I have checked the AndroidManifest contains the package name, which also the same with the package name (applicationId) specified in build.gradle. I am not sure about (3)

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71573938/react-native-error-package-name-not-found

Comment: This is the third query answer I'd like to provide.  Android package names must be distinct and follow to the same guidelines as Java package names. Uppercase and lowercase letters, numerals, and underscores ('_') are permitted. Individual package name parts, on the other hand, can only begin with letters. 
The Android package name must also match the package name of the local project. The current package name may be discovered in the module (app-level) Gradle file, typically in the defaultConfig section of android/app/build.gradle.

Comment: Yeah, the current package name is defined in android/app/build.gradle file